# jquery load / get and dom elements not triggering...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading a simple page using:

```
$.get('../admin/login.php', function(data) { $('#box-contents').html(data); });
```

Now, on this `login.php` page I have an input field, and in my global JavaScript file, I have an event that triggers on `.change()` - but this isn't firing!?

Is this because I have loaded this file on the page so jquery doesn't know that it's now there? Do I need to also include my global JS file within the 'login.php' page too?

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Comment: make sure you're wrapping in the document ready event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using `.get()`, use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) as it was intended for this purpose.  Also for your `.change()` event, you need to either attach it after the element exists (which could be done in your callback below), or you can use `.live()` to attach the event to any current or future DOM elements.

Callback method

```
$('#box-contents').load('../admin/login.php', function() {
    $('input').change(function() {
        //do stuff on change
    });
});
```

Live method

```
$('input').live('change', function() {
    //do stuff on change
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although I'm having the same problems with using .load() -- the event is not firing.